# How to pass a property to abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a Class A that inherits from abstract class B i want to add a property in class A that will be used in the abstract.

```
public class A : B
{

}
```

Example of how i want to use the property in the abstract

```
  public abstract class B
    {
        public const string action = "";

        B(string a)
        {
            a = action;   
        }

        public virtual void test(string _action)
        {
             _action = action;
        }

}
```

Comment: We need to see more about your abstract class & what you've tried

Comment: Show an example usage of that property please.

Comment: public abstract class B
    {
        public const string action = "";

        B(string a)
        {
            a = action;   
        }

        public virtual void test(string _action)
        {
             _action = action;
        }
}
here is the abscract class and here is how i want to use the string

Comment: `a property in class A that will be used in the abstract.` you can't, in any programming language that has inheritance. The *derived* class A can use properties from the parent, not the other way around. If you want a property to be available in both, define that property in the base class

Comment: If you need to use the property in the base class you need to declare it in the base class, possibly as abstract.  But is an abstract class really the right approach? in most cases composition is preferred over inheritance.

Comment: @RadeVignjevic add the code in the question itself. If you want that property in the abstract class, define it there. Another option is to crate a method in the abstract class that accepts parameters for the values it needs.

Comment: The question's code doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to do? Perhaps you need to define the property in the base class, perhaps you really need a design better suited for the problem. Eg you could use an abstract method that's implemented by the derived class instead of a property. Or you could pass a test logger from the outside instead of hard-wiring it into your class. A dummy `ILogger<>` can be used to write stuff to a List you can inspect afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot add something to a child only that will be available in the parent, that is not how inheritance works(children inherit from parents not the other way around).

But if you want to use a property in your parent class that is *overridden* in a child class then yes, it's possible:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassWithName
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }

    public void OutputName() => Console.WriteLine(Name); // using the Name that is initialized in the child class
}

public class ClassWithName : AbstractClassWithName
{
    public ClassWithName(string name) => Name = name;

    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
AbstractClassWithName cwn = new ClassWithName("foo");
cwn.OutputName();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add a property in a child class that will be used in parent class.

To initialize the `property` in base class, You can pass the parameter value to the base class constructor using the `base` keyword.

```
//usage
A a = new A("test");
a.test();
```

pseudo code:

```
public abstract class B
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public B()
    {
    }
    public B(string a)
    {
        action = a;
    }
    public virtual void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(action);
    }
}

public class A : B
{
    public A()
    {
    
    }

    public A(string a) : base(a)
    {
    
    }
}
```